# Enforcing ImageMagick parameters into tex4ht during magick convert (Windows)

Tags: graphics, windows, tex4ht, preamble, htlatex

Use of the newer versions of ImageMagick in Windows with MikTeX and tex4ht requires a trick in the preamble to enforce tex4ht to invoke `magick convert` instead of the previously used convert.exe, which no longer exists in Windows installs.

Given the above, is there a way to at least invoke ImageMagick parameters such as `-trim -density 110x110 -transparent #FFFFFF` by use of the preamble listed below?

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.svg,.png,.jpg}
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}
\Configure{graphics*}
   {eps}
   {\openin15=\csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt\relax%
   \ifeof15%
   \Needs{"magick convert \csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt"}%
   \fi%
   \closein15%
   {\Configure{Needs}{File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt}\Needs{}}%
   \Picture[\csname a:GraphicsAlt\endcsname]{{\csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt} \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname
}}
\ifdefined\HCode\else .... \fi
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{14}{10}{8}
\ConfigureEnv{tabular}
    {\HCode{}}{\HCode{}}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{figure} 
    {\HCode{}}{\HCode{}}{}{}    
\Configure{float}
   {\ifOption{refcaption}{}{\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar \leavevmode}}
   {\HCode{}}
{\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi\EndP \HCode{}\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar}
\Css {body {margin-top: 100px;
                 margin-right: 400px;
                 margin-bottom: 10px;
                 margin-left: 400px;
                }
         }
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in the case of `EPS`, and `PDF` as well, it is best to convert the files to a format supported in HTML before the compilation. It can save a lot of time during the compilation.

If you really want to instruct `tex4ht` to convert them, the important configuration from your config file is this:

```
\Configure{graphics*}
   {eps}
   {\openin15=\csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt\relax%
   \ifeof15%
   \Needs{"magick convert \csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt"}%
   \fi%
   \closein15%
   {\Configure{Needs}{File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt}\Needs{}}%
   \Picture[\csname a:GraphicsAlt\endcsname]{{\csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt} \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname
}}
```

It is a configuration for `eps` graphics. The `\openin` and `\ifeof` commands tests if there is already a converted file, the conversion isn't executed when it exists. The `\csname Gin@base\endcsname` command contains the image base name, without extension. The `\PictExt` contains `tex4ht` picture format, which is `.png` by  default, but you selected `svg` using `\Configure{Picture}{.svg}`.

The `\Needs` command contains the shell command used for the conversion. So if you want to use additional arguments, you should put them here:

```
  \Needs{"magick convert -trim -density 110x110 -transparent \#FFFFFF \csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt"}%
```

BTW, I've found that ImageMagick doesn't really produce good SVG, because it just converts EPS to PNG and then includes it in SVG, so the vector information is lost. I've added the following code to `tex4ht` sources intead:

```
\Needs{"epstopdf '\csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps' && pdf2svg '\csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf' '\csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg'"}
```

This method preserves the vector information, resulting in much higher quality of the resulting image. The downside is that the [pdf2svg](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/) must be installed by the user, as it is not included in TL.

Comment: At run-time, tex4ht didn't like an "F" in the hex color #FFFFFF, so do ticks need to be placed around it?   Can the second `\Needs{}` command be placed immediately below the first inside the `Configure{graphics*}`?

Comment: The `#` must be escaped, I forgot that. Use `\#` instead. Which second `\Needs` do you mean? The one with `epstopdf`, or the empty one used in the configuration?

Comment: The one with `epstopdf`.

Comment: @JoleT ah, I would use that instead of `magick convert`, as it tries to do the same thing, but with a better result

Comment: okay, thanks for the help.

Comment: Using the `\Needs{"epstopdf...` there is an error being thrown for the call: `System call: epstopdf 'myfile.eps' 'myfile.pdf' && pdf2svg 'myfile.pdf' 'myfile.svg'` for which the log file in MiKTeX is stating: `INFO  epstopdf - starting with command line: epstopdf 'myfile.eps' 'myfile.pdf'` and then `FATAL epstopdf - Too many input files.`   I am using `\usepackage{epstopdf}` as well in the .tex file.

Comment: @JoleT do you get the same error even when you execute `epstopdf 'myfile.eps' 'myfile.pdf'` on the terminal?

Comment: Yes, same error for one input .eps file and one output .pdf manually in command mode (DOS).  epstopdf is recognized in the path, so it's installed and working.

Comment: @JoleT I've found that `epstopdf` doesn't work for some files. it is best to use ImageMagick for such files. `tex4ht` shouldn't try to convert existing files again

Comment: In command-line usage, epstopdf works when using only the input filename, like `epstopdf image.eps`.  But pdf2svg is not recognized in the path, is it internal to tex4ht, or do i need a package in MikTeX?   A forum post stated that pdf2svg worked on linux, so maybe not windows.

Comment: @JoleT [pdf2svg](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/) must be installed separately

Comment: Just got it from github and installed 64-bit .exe in PATH.   Can you modify the `\Need{epstopdf...` so that it only calls `epstopf inputfile.eps` only, and then when pdf2svg runs, it uses `pdf2svg inputfile.pdf outputfile.svg`?

Comment: @JoleT I've already updated that

Comment: I'll try this: `\Needs{"epstopdf '\csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps' && pdf2svg '\csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf' '\csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg'"}`

Comment: @JoleT yes, that should be OK

Comment: FYI - epstopdf works manually for `epstopdf converted_graphics/image.eps` but tex4ht is throwing an exception for `epstopdf 'converted_graphics/image.eps'`  It's either the ticks around the command or the && and trying to stuff the pdf2svg on the back end.   Can epstopdf and pdf2svg be broken into two commands in the preamble?

Comment: This worked: `   \Needs{"epstopdf \csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps && pdf2svg \csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf \csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg"}`  Windows DOS did not like the ticks in the command.   Now just need to see if ebb -x image.png in command line does anything?

Comment: Is this correct: `htlatex myfile.tex "myfile.cfg,ebb -x image.png,charset=utf-8,pic-m" " -utf8 -cunihft" `  ?

Comment: Everything works fine without `ebb -x image.png` in command line.  Just change the width and height of images in the `\includegraphics  ` line, for example, I am using `\includegraphics[width=10.67in,height=7.5in,keepaspectratio]{myimage.eps} and the result is a nice 27cm x 21cm image on the xhtml page.

Comment: @JoleT without `''` you will have problems with names containing spaces. does it work if you replace `'` with `"`?

Comment: it worked without the ticks and didn't require quotes either.   Very nice, thanks for the help.

Comment: i took out spaces in image names years ago, since LaTeX doesn't like that.

Comment: @JoleT sure, it is generally bad idea to have spaces in filenames, but we need to support that in tex4ht anyway. I cannot test if the double quotes work on Windows, but it works on Linux